# Updating a SQL table where items to change are identified in another table that is linked

Tags: visual-studio-2005, sql-update

Everywhere I look I can find how to update a table from data in another table but I am not looking for that. I have two tables TABLE1 and TABLE2. TABLE1 has a column PULLDATE and a column JOBNMBR. TABLE2 has a column JOBNMBR and a column PROJECT. The two tables link at the JOBNMBR column. I need to do a bulk update to TABLE1.PULLDATE per a project number, but that project number is stored in TABLE2.PROJECT.

Using VisualStudio 2005 and in VB code not C+, does anyone know the code (if there is any) that links the tables and allows me to update all TABLE1.PULLDATE records grouped by TABLE2.PROJECT? I will be providing the trigger to update using a textbox [TxtBox_Pulldate] and a nearby button [Button_UpdatePulldate].

Thanks a bunch

Chuck Vensel

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand that you want to update Table1 given a matching column in Table2?
You write the SQL update just as you would the `SELECT` except replace the `SELECT` clause with the `UPDATE` clause.

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET 
    [PULLDATE] = your_value
FROM
    Table1
JOIN Table2 
    ON Table2.[JOBNMBR] = Table1.[JOBNMBR]
WHERE 
    Table2.[PROJECT] = your_project_ID
```

Comment: Be sure to vote up helpful answers and mark the correct answer for each question you post.